# La conversión de Mercurial a Git usando fast-export en Windows falla sólo con algunos repositorios

Tags: git, mercurial

En mi empresa tenemos unos cuantos repositorios Mercurial que estamos pensando convertir a Git (usamos Windows). Encontré que hay un script de Python llamado *fast-export* que realiza la conversión, y también [una entrada de blog que explica cómo hacerlo en Windows](https://www.appveyor.com/blog/2014/02/23/converting-mercurial-repository-to-git-on-windows), así que he empezado a convertir algunos repositorios localmente para probar.

El problema es que este procedimiento funciona a la perfección con algunos de nuestros repositorios Mercurial, pero con otros no. En estos casos lo que ocurre es que falla al ejecutar `git checkout HEAD`, con el mensaje de error `pathspec 'HEAD' did not match any file(s) known to git`.

No veo que exista ninguna diferencia significativa entre los repositorios para los que el procedimiento funciona y aquellos para los que no. Son repositorios Mercurial normales con una gran cantidad de *commits* y que tienen ramas *default*, *develop* y *feature/XXX* (estas últimas creadas con `hg flow`).

¿Alguna idea sobre lo que puede estar fallando con esos repositorios?

Comment: No solo el mensaje es raro, sino que es más raro todavía que solo falle con algunos repositorios... Yo probaría a usar el archivo `.py` en vez de el `.sh` con la información de este comentario http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20721700/how-to-use-hg-to-git-tool-fast-export#comment31045001_20722554

Comment: @astrojuanlu Gracias pero ya había visto ese comentario, pero lo que se está sugiriendo es lo que ha yace hg-fast-export.sh (que sí está específicamente diseñado para Windows).

Comment: ¿Un script `.sh` específicamente diseñado para Windows? Supongo que harían bien en crear un `.bat` en su lugar...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bien, al final he conseguido solucionarlo... *usando la fuerza*:

```
hg-fast-export.sh -r repo_path --force
```

El argumento `--force` obra el milagro.

Comment: De todas formas no me quedo tranquilo. Si alguien me dice dónde está el problema y cómo solucionarlo sin usar `--force` le aceptaré la respuesta.